# Let's get answering

Tags: discussion, answers, unanswered-questions

As of today, we have **413 questions** and **399 answers** on our site. Coming off of such a strong and engaged private beta, it's disappointing to see that our answers/question ratio is less than 1. Ideally, we should have 2-3 answers per question, allowing for various points of view to be expressed. While I understand that this is a lofty goal to reach and it can't be accomplished overnight, there's nothing stopping us from answering more of our unanswered questions.

By doing so, we'll have:

- provided a useful answer to a real question about literature
- (possibly) earned rep (and new privileges)
- driven more attention to the question, and as an extension, our site (which can help encourage new users to join)

*As Rand al'Thor points out, while it's important to answer these questions, [it's also important to ensure that the answers are high-quality, thoughtful responses to the question being asked](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390/do-we-have-enough-visitors/401#401)*.

Let's get to work.

Comment: "There are virtually no negatives to this" - but it's *haaaaard* :-P I kid, of course: you're quite right, we really should start knocking out more of those unanswered questions. But we should also be conscientious about it, and make sure those new answers are all *good*, [rather than just answering for the sake of answering](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/a/401/17).

Comment: @Randal'Thor Very true. I've added that to the question, hope you don't mind :)

Comment: Important to note that one should not answer just to make that area51 number go up.

Comment: @Randal'Thor You should post that as an answer..

Comment: Some of the [unanswered questions](https://literature.stackexchange.com/unanswered) are simply [unanswerable](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/727/what-was-the-first-book-that-explicitly-used-a-heros-journey-as-a-checklist). Others have perfectly good answers already, such that it's hard to imagine a new answer coming along that would be better; yet the OPs have [chosen not to accept any](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/493/why-does-robert-frost-contradict-himself-in-the-road-not-taken).

Comment: In addition, I would like to point out that many of the unanswered questions are unanswered because there are just *so many* books, and the small field of users we have now doesn't have the expertise to answer them.  As the site grows, more people will come in who have read those obsolete books, and it will be easier.

Comment: @fi12 I posted it as an answer (sort of) [over here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/837/kill-the-zombies-unanswered-questions) :-)